# How to Authenticate Azure Resource API's Interactive using Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication C#

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I have an app created by VS's  Windows Template Studio. I have the authentication working and I can successfully get a token using the same credentials I use for the Azure portal (Interactive).

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client
...

private IPublicClientApplication _client;

_client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
                  .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                  .WithRedirectUri($"msal{_clientId}://auth")
                  .Build();

var accounts = await _client.GetAccountsAsync();  

_authenticationResult = await _client.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)                                                     
                                     .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                                     .ExecuteAsync();
```

How do I use the token with the Azure API libraries such as:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
- Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Which service do you want to list?

Comment: fixed typo in bullets; i just want to use the token to access Azure Resource .Net Libraries

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the access token to manage Azure resources with
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent SDk. For more details, please refer to [Using authentication token in azure sdk fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147410/using-authentication-token-in-azure-sdk-fluent). The detailed steps are as below.

1. Configure permissions for the Azure AD applications you use.
   [image]
   [image]
2. Code

```
var client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{clientId}://auth")
                .Build();

            var accounts = client.GetAccountsAsync().Result;
            string[] scopes = { "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation" };
            var result = client.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                      .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                                      .ExecuteAsync().Result;

            string subscritionID = ""; // the subciption Id
            string tenantId= "";// the tenata contains the subscription you use
            TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var restClient = RestClient
            .Configure()
            .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .WithCredentials(azureCredentials)
            .Build();
            var azure = Azure
                .Authenticate(restClient, tenantId)
                .WithSubscription(subscritionID);
            var sp = azure.ResourceGroups.List();
            foreach (var group in sp) {

                Console.WriteLine("group name :"+ group.Name);
            }
```

[image]

Besides, regarding the sdk [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication), it is also used to enable service to authenticate to Azure services. In other words, it is another way to get the token. But it only supports authentication with [Azure MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/context/msi-context#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

Comment: Worked, but I had to provide '.WithAuthority("https://login.windows.net/xx-xx-xx-xx-xx", true)'.  I am building this app to connect to any Azure Tenant. I would like to provide a list of Tenants (before of after login) Is there a way to get the tenants associated to a UserID.

Comment: @jlo-gmail If you want to get one user's all tenants, you can use the rest api ```GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-06-01```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list

Comment: @jlo-gmail Do you have any other concerns?